# Constructing the approximate confidence set for parameter vector beta in least square regression

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, references, least-squares

From Elements of Statistical Learning, on page 49 (in the context of least square regression), we are given the approximate confidence set (shown in image) for the parameter vector $\beta$.

[image]

I want to implement this in R. However, I have no idea how to make $\beta$ as the subject,i.e. I could not construct the confidence set in the following form

$$\beta \leq \hat{\sigma}^2 \chi^2_{p+1} \times something$$

I don't really know how to rearrange the terms (of the confidence set from the image).

Can someone kindly help me out here please ?

Comment: What is the dimension of $\beta $ ?  You won't get anything pretty unless it is 3 or less.  Its essentially an "ellipse" but in more than two dimensions.

Comment: Suppose the dimension of $\beta$ is 3 x 1, how would you approach this problem ? Thanks. Because I am completely clueless right now.